# How to import files from github and host it on any other site

Tags: github, openshift

I guess this is not the best place to post this. Please if it is not accepted here can you point me to another StackOverflow site where I can post this.

**Here is what I am asking.**

I have an **index.html** which I want to import and host to my openshit Redhat account.
https://github.com/areaboy/myfirstdata/tree/master/adminmanager/index.html

my issue is that when I entered the above url in my openshift redhat Import source location.
It throws errors.

Please what is the proper way of cloning the git files and then upload to openshift
Below is the screenshot of the openshift Import Git repository url:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's asking for a repository URI, in your case it would be

> https://github.com/areaboy/myfirstdata

Then I don't know if your file needs to be at the root of your repository or if you can give him a path later on.

Also note that it's asking for a http URI and Github is using https.

Comment: In that case does that means that I have to first upload the files to my online site which uses http and then  send the link to openshift. Is this right

Comment: Depends on what you want to do, if it's just hosting the html file, you can use the https github uri and it should work juste fine.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to give the **.git** url of your repository not the path of your **index.html** file for importing.

[image]

Go to url:- https://github.com/areaboy/myfirstdata

Click on the **clone or download** button you will get the url for your git repository now give this url while importing.

[image]

Copy the **url** and give it while importing the project in openshift.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer is also useful so am upvoting